# If $W$,$V$ are open sets and $Z$ is dense, then $\overline{W}\cap Z\subseteq V\implies \overline{W}\subseteq\overline{V}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Is this true? I hope it is. I'm trying to draw a picture but I'm getting confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems valid. Suppose $W,V$ are open sets, $Z$ is dense, and $\overline{W}\cap Z\subseteq V$.
Fix $x\in\overline{W}$.
To show $x\in\overline{V}$, we prove that every neighborhood of $x$ meets $V$.
To this end, suppose $U$ is open such that $x\in U$.
Since $x\in\overline{W}$, we know that $U$ meets $W$.
Hence $U\cap W$ is a nonempty open set.
Since $Z$ is dense, it meets $U\cap W$.
Hence there is $z\in U\cap W\cap Z$, so that
$$z\in U\cap W\cap Z \subseteq W\cap Z \subseteq \overline{W}\cap Z \subseteq V.$$
Thus $z\in U\cap V$, which shows that $V$ meets $U$.
Therefore $x\in\overline{V}$.

Note that we didn't need $V$ to be an open set.